# Error: RestAdapter(...) has private access in 'retrofit.RestAdapter'

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I am trying to make a class the uses Retrofit to make some API calls.

```
public class RedditUtils {

private RestAdapter restAdapter;
private RedditApiService service;
private final String redditBaseUrl = "https://oauth.reddit.com";

public RedditUtils()
{
    restAdapter = new RestAdapter().Builder().setEndpoint(redditBaseUrl).build();

    service = restAdapter.create(RedditApiService.class);
}

public void fetchToken(String token)
{
    service.getToken(token, new Callback<RedditAccessToken>() {
        @Override
        public void success(RedditAccessToken redditAccessToken, Response response) {
            Log.d("RedditAccessToken", redditAccessToken.getAccessToken());
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

            Log.d("RedditAccessTokenFailed", error.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

}

When I set restAdapter equalt to new RestAdapter(), I get the error

```
 RestAdapter(*long path name*) has private access in 'retrofit.RestAdapter'
```

I am not sure what would be causing this error and I haven't found anyone else with this issue.  Any ideas on how to solve the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't suppose to instantiate `RestAdapter`, hence why it has a private constructor.

`Builder` is a static internal class of the `RestAdapter` class. You can instantiate it like so:

```
new RestAdapter.Builder()
```